# CKEditor export as word docment

Tags: ckeditor

I'm using CKEditor for enabling editing and I've requirement to export it to other formats.

Is it feasible to export the content of CKEditor as .doc format ? 
Any help or refrence would be of great help.

Thanks,

Comment: *In case you don't find a better solution or you're ok with an out-of-browser solution:* If you render CKEditor's output in the browser, you could save it to your desktop, and use a tool like [pandoc - a command line tool](http://pandoc.org/) to convert it to different formats (Like .doc).

Comment: "CKEditor is not an application that can convert or save documents to any specific file format, like .docx or PDF" [See more](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_basics-section-what-ckeditor-is-not).

Answer (score 0):

It could be worth to see bellow.
https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1193272/Convert-HTML-to-Word-document-using-CKEditor-and-M

The link explains how to create Office word from ckeditor with MariGold.OpenXHTML.

Hope this helps.